# Python - How do i perform operations on my own class in both directions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, error-handling

For example, let my class = object

when i do `print(object * int)` everything goes well

However, when i do print(int * object). i receive an error in which my class object cannot be added to the int object, is this a issue resolvable without changing the default data types?

Answer (score 1):

If you override __mul__, you can call print(object*int).

If you override __rmul__, you can call print(int*object).

When a*b is written, it prioritizes calling a.__mul__(b), and if that is not implemented, calls b.__rmul__(a)